# Including a footer an every slide with Rmarkdown and revealjs

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, reveal.js

My company requires all internal+external presentations to use an approved footer for every slide, which pushes everyone to copy and paste things into PowerPoint.

However, I would love to use R notebooks to make revealjs_presentation slide decks. Could anyone provide a simple example of a Rmarkdown notebook (or pandoc template?) I could modify that does this?

I imagine this would be useful for a lot of people at a lot of companies.

Comment: With revealJS each slide is in <section> elements.  If you put a <p> element at the end of the <div class="slides"> then it puts it on every slide.  You could then style this how you needed to. Here is a presentation I gave at a conference which had a button as a footer on each slide: http://thejoshdean.com/fusion2017/

Comment: Thanks, Josh. Adding `<p style="font-size:12px">Restricted</p>` at that location is probably good enough for me.

Comment: I'm hoping someone from the R community could shed light on how I could automate this within the R notebook framework, so I can get others in my company on-board.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible to add a fixed footer on all slides using the `includes` parameter/argument in `revealjs::revealjs_presentation`. (With much thanks to the earlier commenters for their suggestions which made me think of this).

For example, I wanted to add a corporate logo and a disclaimer footer to each slide. I created a HTML file to be included before the document body with the following contents:

```
<div id="header-footer">
  <img class="slide-logo" src="corporate-logo.png"/>
  <p class="slide-footer">Corporate disclaimer</p>
</div>
```

I then included this snippet before the body of the document with the `includes` parameter in the YAML header of my R markdown document (Rmd file):

```
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    css: styles.css
    includes:
      in_header: header.html
```

Then, to position the logo in the top right and have the footer fixed at the bottom of each slide, I used the following CSS (stored in `styles.css`):

```
/********** Customise logo, and footer disclaimer **********/
/* Position the corporate logo in the top right of the page */
#header-footer .slide-logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 150px;
}


/* Style/position the footer text */
#header-footer .slide-footer {
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 65%;
}
```

Of course, you can play with the CSS to style it how you would like.

One restriction is that this places the logo and footer on *every* slide, including the title (but except for slides with a whole-slide background image, which hides the disclaimer and logo). I'm currently trying to figure out a way to restrict logo/disclaimer for certain slides.

I have yet to do it, but it *should* be possible to wrap this up in to a custom template to integrate directly with new RMarkdown documents for your organisation, e.g. see chapters 17 and 18 for doing that in the [RMarkdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/document-templates.html).

I hope this is still of some use to you/others.